# Report Viewer Not Finding Report Server?

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013

It's been awhile since I've used Visual Studio. Today, I'm creating a basic Windows Form application (C#) that has a report view in the form.

I have the Report Viewer element in my form. It has an easy window to set the Report Server URL and the Report Path.

I assigned both of these fields with the URL to my SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 R2 instance. I verified it's working by loading it up in my Internet Explorer browser. I did the same by copying and pasting the URL path to the specific report I'm trying to run in the Report Path field.

When building and running the application, I get 404 errors that it can't find the service in the Report Viewer. The URL to SSRS is right, the report path looks good, I can view both of the paths and so forth. Is there a setting i'm missing in SSRS or something?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. SSRS was set to native mode and I have to specify the native path.

```
Native mode: /Adventureworks 2008 Sample Reports/Company Sales 2008
```